# FB.Canvas.setSize not working on Linked pages

Tags: php, facebook

I have followed through the instructions from other posts on the FB.Canvas.setSize function to increase the height for the canvas iframe, and placed the code in the main index.php file.

When clicking a link from the main page to another page, the FB.Canvas.setSize is not working for the new link. Do I have to set FB.init and FB.Canvas.setSize for every page ? Or is there something I am missing ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call FB.Canvas.setSize every time you reload the page. Maybe you should consider using setAutoGrow?
You can use FB.Canvas.setSize at body.onload

Comment: If you need to call it before site is displayed by browser you can also use DOMContentLoad event by setting handler for this event. You can achive it calling addEventListener but if site is simple the body.onload should be fine.

Comment: just tried it. still not working. i added into the linked page; <body onLoad="FB.Canvas.setsize({ width: 500, height: 1000 });"> Do I have to call anything else, or add the function for FB.Canvas ?

Comment: Remember that linked site also need to call FB.init(), if it still not works you can show me this page and I will tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Oh, so every page linked from the main page which has FB.init() must have the same function on it ?

Comment: Sure thing, FB.init needs to be called when the site is loaded. In other way the FB object will not be initialized. JavaScript objects after refreshing or changing site will be cleared.